# VS Code: Can't Type in Terminal (Automatic Redirect for User Input)

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm having a lot of trouble when clicking on my "run" button in Visual Studio Code. My code builds successfully, and it'll ask me to enter any keyword or type anything to close the terminal. That's normal.

But my program should allow user input, so I need to type inside the terminal. However, I'm unable to type anything at all since the terminal closing automatically (upon clicking/typing anything) redirects me to a new terminal window with one line such as *name@names-MacBook-Pro CSProjects %  *

So I can't act as a user inputting anything in my program (C++) at all when, of course, I need to input things to test my program. This happened randomly and I've tried everything from redownloading VS Code to searching for answers online (found none).

Tried redownloading VS Code. Regardless of what version of "run" that I click (such as the dropdown options like debug, run C++ file, etc), I get the same result.

[Program Build Success Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBbfJ.png)

Comment: Avoid images of text. Post the text itself in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Terminal saying `Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`   is the terminal used by the compiler.
It doesn't run your program. The compilation process is configured by a `tasks.json` in your .vscode directory, and is executed in this terminal that may be reused by the compiler

Your run button will start yor program in *another* terminal - the one you will be redirected to after closing your first one by pressing any key.

Its this new terminal that is expecting your input!

---

By the way, your compiler has created an executable with the same name as your cpp file, but with an .exe extension.
You can run this file from the terminal by typing the name of the file if you are in the correct directory.